# Could Bushi Ban martial arts prepare me for the Olympics?

Tags: karate

I am a novice in bushi ban style. I need to know can i participate in olympics after completing my study? or olympics allows only few styles (like tae-kwon-do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Olympic combat sports are freestyle wrestling, Greco-Roman wrestling, Tae Kwon Do, judo, and boxing. If bushi ban prepared you for one of those then you could compete in the Olympics, but that is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Fencing is also an Olympic combat sport, coming in three varieties (foil, epee, and saber).

Comment: @DavidH.Clements I apologize for my bias towards unarmed combat. Perhaps you could you edit my answer to include fencing? I assume firearms don't count because combat sports require competition against a live opponent instead of a target.